# Appending a list to a dictionary to get a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have been trying to figure out how to add a list to a dictionary and get a nested list in a dictionary value as a result. Here is a dummy code as an example:

```
IN:

pets = dict()
pets['cat'] = list(['stray','brown','big'])
new_val = list(['house','white','small'])
pets['cat'].append(new_val)
print(pets)

OUT:
{'cat': ['stray', 'brown', 'big', ['house', 'white', 'small']]}
```

I am trying to get a list of two lists instead:

```
{'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'], ['house', 'white', 'small']]}
```

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept one (green tick on left), otherwise feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way, in my opinion, is to instantiate the value as an empty list. Then append lists sequentially.

```
pets = {}
pets['cat'] = []

old_val = ['stray','brown','big']
pets['cat'].append(old_val)

new_val = ['house','white','small']
pets['cat'].append(new_val)
```

If you do this often, use `collections.defaultdict` so you don't have to instantiate keys and empty lists manually:

```
from collection import defaultdict

pets = defaultdict(list)

old_val = ['stray','brown','big']
pets['cat'].append(old_val)

new_val = ['house','white','small']
pets['cat'].append(new_val)
```

Result:

```
{'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'],
         ['house', 'white', 'small']]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you didn't create `pets["cat"]` as a 2-dimensional list.  So the minimum viable fix is to change

```
list(['stray','brown','big'])
```

to

```
list([['stray','brown','big']])
```

But you really don't need `list([...])`.  This method essentially converts whatever is passed to type "list." Since you've already created a list with `[]`, you don't need to call `list()`.  The result is casting a list to a list, so it just returns the list.  You can see if you do `list(pets)`, you get a list of the keys of your dictionary.   This is how dictionaries are converted to lists (dropping the values and making a list out of the keys).  If you pass it a single string, it creates a list with that string.  If you pass it nothing, it creates an empty list.

So:

```
pets['cat'] = list(['stray','brown','big'])
new_val = list(['house','white','small'])
```

Should be

```
pets['cat'] = [['stray','brown','big']]
new_val = ['house','white','small']
```

OUT:

```
{'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'], ['house', 'white', 'small']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach too:

```
list_1=[['stray','brown','big'],['house','white','small']]

key='cat'
dict_1={}
for i in list_1:
    if key not in dict_1:
        dict_1[key]=[i]
    else:
        dict_1[key].append(i)
print(dict_1)
```

output:

```
{'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'], ['house', 'white', 'small']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible abstraction, also using `defaultdict`.

**Code**

```
import collections as ct


def append_lists(key, *iterables, defaultdict_=None):
    """Return a dict of lists."""
    if defaultdict_ is None:
        dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    else:
        dd = defaultdict_.copy()

    for lst in iterables:
        dd[key].extend(lst)
    return dd
```

**Demo**

Build a dict of lists given a key and an iterable of lists:

```
lists = ["stray", "brown", "big"], ["house", "white", "small"]

d = append_lists("cat", lists)
d
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'], ['house', 'white', 'small']]})
```

Continue adding entries to the original dict:

```
append_lists("dog", [["big", "wide", "yellow"]], defaultdict_=d)
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'], ['house', 'white', 'small']],
#              'dog': [['big', 'wide', 'yellow']]})
```

Notice, the original dictionary is preserved:

```
d
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'cat': [['stray', 'brown', 'big'], ['house', 'white', 'small']]})
```

Finally, we can build from simple lists of keys and items:

```
animals = ["mouse", "bird"]
features = (
    [["small", "brown", "cute"], ["small", "white", "fast"]], 
    [["large", "black", "fast"]]
)

result = ct.defaultdict(list)
for k, items in zip(animals, features):
    result = append_lists(k, items, defaultdict_=result)

result
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'bird': [['large', 'black', 'fast']],
#              'mouse': [['small', 'brown', 'cute'],
#               ['small', 'white', 'fast']]})
```